# Can we display live cloud images over google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api v3 to create a [weather website](http://social.ndtv.com/static/Weather/report/).

Can we display live clouds over this page?

Does google map offer any functionality to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this be updated with the new google maps?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API does not provide data about clouds or (as far as I know, anyway) any weather data.  You'd need to get that from somewhere else.

Once you have that data, you'll need to generate an image from it (or use an image generated for you, I suppose).

Once you have the image, you can use one of the various overlay types detailed in the API v3 doc to overlay it on your map, setting the opacity appropriately.

The Google Maps API v3 overlay is probably the easiest step in the chain here.

Comment: Ya, I am also using clouds from barnabu (http://www.barnabu.co.uk/global-cloud-animation/) and I am overlaying it. But the point is you cant assure that information is correct since you are fixing the cloud as overlay on he desired area with hit-n-try approach. Also if google maps will offer such functionality then information will be correct.